# How to bookmark lines from/to

Tags: notepad++, bookmarks, emeditor

In Emeditor/notepad++, I have like 15 million lines.

Is it possible to bookmark lines from 1 line to 1503232? or from 3500000 to 5200005?

Comment: What's the meaning of `15mln`?

Comment: I mean that my notepad got 15 milions lines and i want select for an example from first line to 5200005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use **EmEditor**, to select from 1 to 1503232:

1. Go to Line 1, press <kbd>F8</kbd> to start a selection by keyboard.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to bring the **Jump** dialog box. Enter `1503232` to the **Line** box. Click **OK**.
3. Press <kbd>F8</kbd> again to finish the selection by keyboard.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to set bookmarks on the selected lines.

Answer (score -1):

- Go to the numbers pane on the left side of the app and click.
- A blue blob should appear in the pane.
- Then hit <kbd>F2</kbd> and notepad++ app will scroll through all bookmarks in numeric order.

Comment: You should've modified your original post to add additional information, not post a separate answer. Anyway, please delete your older answer now. Thank you :)